# Are there any disadvantages using implicit casts for variables?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

In wf4, you can bind variables and constants to InArguments or OutArguments in 2 ways,
using the explicit syntax:

```
Variable<string> nameOfPerson = new Variable<string>();

new Assign { 
  To = new OutArgument<string>(nameOfPerson),
  Value = new InArgument<string>("Name")
}
```

or you can use the implicit syntax

```
new Assign {
    To = nameOfPerson,
    Value = "Name"
}
```

Are there any disadvantages using the second syntax, such as maybe performance?

**UPDATE**

Apparently,

```
new Assign { 
    To = nameOfPerson,
    Value="name"
}
```

does not work, but this does work

```
new Assign {
    To = new OutArgument<string>(nameOfPerson),
    Value = new InArgument<string>("name")
}
```

for the Value property, you can use implicit:

```
var anotherVariable = new Variable<string();

new Assign {
    To = new OutArgument<string>(nameOfPerson),
    Value = anotherVariable
}
```

It's confusing when you can use implicit and when not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, in the end the same code executes. The only extra code is the implicit cast from Variable to InArgument but that is just a constructor call so no extra overhead.